# Inner join same master table three different columns from three different tables based on which is not null

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using following query to get the results so far but now I need to change in below query so instead of three queries and union , I can get the result in one single query

```
SELECT spec.name FROM mst_specification  as spec 
inner join mst_lineitem_type as subsubcat on spec.lineitem_type_id=subsubcat.id 
union 
SELECT spec.name FROM mst_specification  as spec 
inner join mst_subcategory as subcat on spec.subcategory_id=subcat.id 
union 
SELECT spec.name FROM mst_specification  as spec 
inner join quote_categories as cat on spec.category_id=cat.id ;
```

**Edit based on comments :**

I need to use same `mst_specification` table in join with another tables

```
SELECT * FROM mst_quote_type as qt 
INNER Join quote_categories as cat on qt.id=cat.quote_type_id
INNER JOIN mst_subcategory as subcat on cat.id=subcat.quote_category_id 
INNER JOIN mst_lineitem_type as subsubcat on subcat.id= subsubcat.subcategory_id
INNER JOIN quote_lineitem_library as item on subsubcat.id=item.lineitem_type_id
INNER JOIN mst_uom as uom on uom.id=item.uom_id ;
```

Comment: Provide some sample data (CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO, 3-5 rows per table) and desired output for this data.

Comment: `UNION` joins the tables vertically and `JOIN` horizontally, as long as you  need the information as rows , you are on the right track

Comment: Why do you 'need' to do that?

Comment: @MatBailie updated question based on why I need that

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions.

Comment: It's still not at all clear what you want or why. Please read Jarlh's link and prepare a full example to demonstrate your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Left Join the tables on their id's.

> ```
> SELECT DISTINCT 
>   spec.name as spec_name
> , cat.name as cat_name
> , qt.name as qt_name
> , subcat.name as subcat_name
> , subsubcat.name as subsubcat_name
> , item.name as item_name
> , uom. name as uom_name
> FROM mst_specification AS spec
> LEFT JOIN quote_categories AS cat 
>   ON cat.id = spec.category_id
> LEFT JOIN mst_quote_type AS qt
>   ON qt.id = cat.quote_type_id
> LEFT JOIN mst_subcategory AS subcat 
>   ON subcat.quote_category_id = cat.id
> LEFT JOIN mst_lineitem_type AS subsubcat 
>   ON subsubcat.subcategory_id = subcat.id
> LEFT JOIN quote_lineitem_library AS item 
>   ON item.lineitem_type_id = subsubcat.id
> LEFT JOIN mst_uom AS uom 
>   ON uom.id = item.uom_id
> ORDER BY spec.name, 2, 3, 4;
> ```

| spec_name | cat_name | qt_name | subcat_name | subsubcat_name | item_name | uom_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| spec 1 | cat 1 | quote type 1 | subcat 1 | lineitem type 1 | line item lib 1 | uom 1 |
| spec 2 | cat 2 | quote type 2 | subcat 2 | lineitem type 2 | item item lib 2 | uom 2 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=293f10e204848835d25024a2017bf535)*

But if you just need the specification names

> ```
> SELECT DISTINCT name as spec_name
> FROM mst_specification
> ORDER BY name
> ```

| spec_name |
| --- |
| spec 1 |
| spec 2 |

Answer (score 1):

You want to select the spec names where an ID exists in another table. Use `EXISTS` or `IN` for these lookups.

```
select spec.name 
from mst_specification spec 
where spec.lineitem_type_id in (select id from mst_lineitem_type)
   or spec.subcategory_id in (select id from mst_subcategory)
   or spec.category_id in (select id from quote_categories)
order by spec.name;
```

The question remains why you want to do this. With a proper database built with foreign keys, an ID should always refer to a row in the parent table. So what you have here can be boiled down to

```
select spec.name 
from mst_specification spec 
where spec.lineitem_type_id is not null
   or spec.subcategory_id is not null
   or spec.category_id is not null
order by spec.name;
```

Or, if you also see it guaranteed (maybe because of a check constraint) that one of the IDs is not null:

```
select spec.name 
from mst_specification spec 
order by spec.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

It ***appears*** that you just want to add three spec lookups to your existing query.

If so, just join like normal, but give each occurrence of the spec tab a different alias...

```
SELECT * FROM mst_quote_type as qt 
INNER Join quote_categories as cat on qt.id=cat.quote_type_id
INNER JOIN mst_subcategory as subcat on cat.id=subcat.quote_category_id 
INNER JOIN mst_lineitem_type as subsubcat on subcat.id= subsubcat.subcategory_id
INNER JOIN quote_lineitem_library as item on subsubcat.id=item.lineitem_type_id
INNER JOIN mst_uom as uom on uom.id=item.uom_id

INNER JOIN mst_specification AS spec_subsubcat ON spec_subsubcat.lineitem_type_id=subsubcat.id 

INNER JOIN mst_specification AS spec_subcat ON spec_subcat.subcategory_id=subcat.id 

INNER JOIN mst_specification AS spec_cat ON spec_cat.category_id=cat.id
```

Your question title does mention nulls, though you don't explain that in the question, so perhaps only one of the three category levels actually has a key? In which case you may want...

```
SELECT *, COALESCE(spec_cat.name, spec_subcat.name, spec_subsubcat.name)
FROM mst_quote_type as qt 
INNER Join quote_categories as cat on qt.id=cat.quote_type_id
INNER JOIN mst_subcategory as subcat on cat.id=subcat.quote_category_id 
INNER JOIN mst_lineitem_type as subsubcat on subcat.id= subsubcat.subcategory_id
INNER JOIN quote_lineitem_library as item on subsubcat.id=item.lineitem_type_id
INNER JOIN mst_uom as uom on uom.id=item.uom_id

LEFT JOIN mst_specification AS spec_subsubcat ON spec_subsubcat.lineitem_type_id=subsubcat.id 

LEFT JOIN mst_specification AS spec_subcat ON spec_subcat.subcategory_id=subcat.id 

LEFT JOIN mst_specification AS spec_cat ON spec_cat.category_id=cat.id
```

The `LEFT JOIN`s ensure the join happens if possible or yields NULLs if not possible. Then, the `SELECT` uses a `COALESCE()` to return the first not-null name.

(Picks the category spec name if there is one. Picks the sub category spec name if there is no category spec name. Picks the sub sub category spec name if the other two are not present.)